# Center window component

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have create a window component but it will randomly position whether I open its window, x and y positions will only offset the elements, not window. How do I position it to the center of the screen?

Flex 4 (AS3):

```
private function openDoc():void {
    if (newWindow != null) newWindow.close();
    newWindow = new docwin();
    newWindow.width = 500;
    newWindow.height = 320;
    newWindow.type = "normal";
    newWindow.systemChrome = "standard";
    newWindow.transparent = false;
    newWindow.setStyle("showFlexChrome", true);
    newWindow.showStatusBar = false;
    newWindow.minimizable = false;
    newWindow.maximizable = false;
    newWindow.resizable = false;
    newWindow.open();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
newWindow.x = Math.ceil((Capabilities.screenResolutionX - newWindow.width) / 2);
newWindow.y = Math.ceil((Capabilities.screenResolutionY - newWindow.height) / 2);
```

Comment: Actually add this into Window component with the "this.nativewindow" instead of "newWindow" to each line does work. newWindow is a component, not a nativeWindow, very confusing for many parts in Flex 4 and AIR 2 already. Math.ceil is optional. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

You can use layout property of window like horizontalCentre and verticalCentre  use contstraint based layout scheme

Comment: No. This is not related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to position the new window with reference to stageWidth and stageHeight properties.

Assuming the origin of your new window is top left, the new location of the the windows will be:

(Stage.stageWidth - newWindow.width)/2, (Stage.stageHeight - newWindow.height)/2;

Comment: How about showing a full code? Have no idea how to use with your code. And does it applicable for "Window" component?

Comment: Use it as per Michaels' answer - Capabilites.screenResolutionX gives you the screen size of the device, eg a PC screen at 1024x768. The stageWidth gives you the actual size of the player element in a page. hth